# how I can schedule tweepy script to run every hour?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

This is simple code I wrote to scrape data from twitter using tweepy.

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date


####input your credentials here
consumer_key = '(Hidden)'
consumer_secret = '(Hidden)'
access_token = '(Hidden)'
access_token_secret = '(Hidden)'
today = date.today()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvFile = open('remotejob.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#jobs #remote",count=5000,
                           lang="en",
                           since=today,tweet_mode = 'extended').items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.id)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.id, tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.statuses_count, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count])
```

How can I schedule it to run every hour automatically?

Comment: If you are using ubuntu OS, you can use crontab. For windows you can use Task scheduler

Comment: Or you can `import time` then write a endless loop with `while True:` and `time.sleep(3600)` at the end of the loop.